# My laptop occasionally freezes for a short time

Tags: laptop, freeze

I just bought a brand new gaming laptop and I'm having some issues. It's very powerful and I can run really good games on it with high visuals, I'm happy with that. The issue is that my games have very short freezes every so often: even the ones with no good specs requirement... It's not that annoying on chill games, but I play some really nervous games and these lags happen so often it becomes really annoying and punishing. I don't know what causes that because my specs shouldn't be the problem here and I can't believe that buying a laptop over a desktop is that cruel. Is there anything to do or should I give up and play these nervous games on my old desktop with lower graphics?

My specs (MSI KATANA 17 B13V):

- Win11 64bit running on Intel SSD
- Intel i9
- 16GB RAM
- nVidia Geforce RTX 4070

Comment: What diagnostics have you completed? Have you checked Event Viewer to see if there are warnings or messages from your OS that correspond to these blips? Have you tested the memory and disk? What games, specifically? Simply listing specs does not give us enough information to begin figuring out what may be the issue, and we cannot advise on whether or not you should go back to a desktop for the same reason. Please edit your question to add any and all information you can.

Comment: Also you should update all drivers, so please let us know about updates as well

Comment: Is the issues with *online* games only? If so, then look to the internet connection. Also, check to see what background processes are running and how much CPU, GPU and Disk I/O are in use. Finally, check if updates are running in the background.

Comment: Ok so I updated ONE driver and it seems to be fixed? I don't know if it is just pure luck and I didn't have any blips by coincidence or because it really is alright now. Event Viewer didn't show me anything related to these lags before I updated this driver so I hope this is it because I don't know what other information I could provide you. I'll come back to this post later if anything happens in the next few days. Thanks!